# SELECT n rows WHERE n-1 rows exist before date

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to create a MySQL query where it will select the newest 4 rows (sorted by `date` DESC, Y-m-d format) where the newest `date` is after `date_x` and at least 3 rows before `date_x+1` exist. For example consider the following records:

```
-----------------------
|  id  |     date     | 
|   1  |  2018-01-01  |
|   6  |  2018-01-02  |
|  10  |  2018-01-03  |
|  26  |  2018-01-04  |
|  27  |  2018-01-05  |
|  34  |  2018-01-06  |
|  60  |  2018-01-07  |
-----------------------
```

If `date_x` = '0000-00-00' it should return:

```
-----------------------
|  id  |     date     | 
|   1  |  2018-01-01  |
|   6  |  2018-01-02  |
|  10  |  2018-01-03  |
|  26  |  2018-01-04  |
-----------------------
```

If `date_x` = '2018-01-04' it should return:

```
-----------------------
|  id  |     date     | 
|  27  |  2018-01-02  |
|  34  |  2018-01-03  |
|  60  |  2018-01-04  |
|  27  |  2018-01-05  |
-----------------------
```

If `date_x` = '2018-01-07' it should return:

```
-----------------------
|  id  |     date     |
-----------------------
```

Is there any way of doing this efficiently with one query?

Comment: Are you sure it is sorted by `date desc`?

Comment: The format is Y-m-d, my apologies this wasn't clear from the original post. I've edited it.

Comment: What is "date_x+1"? And "after date_x" would suggest when date_x = '2018-01-04', the results would not include dates before then.

Comment: If `date_x = '0000-00-00' ` what is date_x + 1? I cant see how you get that result

Comment: Downvoted because you need to describe what you have already tried/thought through and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrations supply value `'2018-01-04'` for `date_x`

Get count of rows before "`date_x + 1`". (We can compare this to a literal value to determine if there are at least 3 rows.)

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
   FROM mytable d
  WHERE d.date <  '2018-01-04'  + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Get count of rows with `date` value after `date_x`. (We can compare this to a literal to determine if there's a[t least one] row with `date` value after `date_x`.)

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
   FROM mytable c
  WHERE c.date >  '2018-01-04'  + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

Get (up to) four newest rows...

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.date
   FROM mytable t
  ORDER BY t.date DESC
  LIMIT 4
```

Putting that all together, we can do something like this

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.date
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE 2 < ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
                FROM mytable d
               WHERE d.date <  '2018-01-04'  + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            )
    AND 0 < ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
                FROM mytable c
               WHERE c.date >  '2018-01-04'  + INTERVAL 0 DAY
            )
  ORDER BY t.date DESC
  LIMIT 4
```

Other query patterns can achieve equivalent result, for example:

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.date
   FROM mytable t
   JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
            FROM mytable d
           WHERE d.date <  '2018-01-04'  + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        ) q
     ON q.cnt > 2
   JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
            FROM mytable c
           WHERE c.date >  '2018-01-04'  + INTERVAL 0 DAY
        ) r
     ON r.cnt > 0
  ORDER BY t.date DESC
  LIMIT 4
```

---

The query returns rows in descending date order.  If we want to reorder those rows, we can wrap that whole query in parens and reference it as an inline view

```
SELECT z.id
     , z.date
  FROM (
          -- query goes here
       ) z
 ORDER BY z.date ASC
```

The specification isn't entirely clear... what if there are fewer than four rows? What if there is more than one row with date > date_x + 1?

I suspect there is more to the specification that I didn't catch. Spec says we want the "newest date" to be *after* date_x, ...  it wasn't clear if we should return only the *first* date after `date_x`, and disregard later dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the gist of what you are trying to do:

```
select t.*
from t
where date >= @date and
      (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.date >= @date) >= 3
order by date
limit 4;
```

Your question and sample data are quite confusing.  You say order by `date desc`, but the sample results seem to have the smallest dates first.  You mention `x_date + 1`, but that is not anywhere in the results.  I think the above does what you want.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c32009/7 Probably need invert some conditionals because doesnt match OP desire output and also need one greater than the date